I have some items on my app, I don't want the user to choose an item twice but my logic is not working
In my provider I have defined some logics so that if the user chooses an item twice then I will return and do nothing:
void addCoffee(Coffee coffee) async {
    if (state.contains(coffee) == true) {
      return;
    } else {
      final db = await _getDatabase();
      await db.insert(
        'cart_provider',
        {
          'id': coffee.id,
          'coffeeImage': coffee.coffeeImage,
          'CoffeeName': coffee.coffeeName,
          'CoffeePrice': coffee.coffeePrice,
        },
      );

      state = [...state, coffee];
    }
  }

and here in another file I am passing the coffee item to my riverpod provider:
InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    ref.read(cartProvider.notifier).addCoffee(widget.coffee);
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (ctx) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          contentTextStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                          ),
                          content: const Text(
                            'Successfully added to cart',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  });
                },
                splashColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 43, 35, 35),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                child: Container(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                  width: 300,
                  height: 65,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    'Add to cart',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

I really don't know why it's not working, since I have started to save data through sqflite package I have this problem.
I have checked my codes a few times but I can not find the problem.
if you need more information please text me

can you share the code of Coffee

I could suppose that you must add async/await in your coffee add function
    onTap: () async {
                 await _addCoffee(cardProvider,widget.coffee);
                },
    ...
      _addCoffee(
      {required CardProvider cardProvider, required Coffee coffee}) async {
    await ref.read(cartProvider.notifier).addCoffee(coffee);
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) {
        return AlertDialog(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          contentTextStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          ),
          content: const Text(
            'Successfully added to cart',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Approve'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

also , i don't understand why you use SetState if you pop? Also, i suggest you check result from database query, and if it's satisfactory call next action. Give more info about your actions please
Something like that should work
